# Add subviews on Customize UIView works not as expect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I subclass a class of `UIView` called:`AURTabView`. Then I drag 3 views(white background) to storyboard to auto layout them with 1/3 screen width of each. Then i add a `UIButton` on the `init` method, it works well so far as below:[image]

Then i want to add another two `UIView`s on to them. The weird thing is the first and third `AUTRabView` works as expect, but the middle one doesn't.

[image]

This is really weird. I checked UIView hierarchy like below:[image]

Any point?

Here is the code:

```
class AURTabView: UIView {

    let tabButton   = UIButton()
    let smallCircle = UIView()
    let largeCircle = UIView()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.addSubview(tabButton)
        self.addSubview(smallCircle)
        self.addSubview(largeCircle)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let height = self.frame.height
        tabButton.frame = CGRect(x: (self.frame.width-height)/2, y: 0, width: height, height: height)
        tabButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        smallCircle.frame = CGRect(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-2.5, y: height-10-8, width: 5, height: 5)
        smallCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        largeCircle.frame = CGRect(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-5, y: height-8, width: 10, height: 10)
        largeCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        print(smallCircle)
        print(largeCircle)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        tabButton.layer.cornerRadius = tabButton.frame.width/2
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
import UIKit
```

class AURTabView: UIView {

```
let tabButton   = UIButton()
let smallCircle = UIView()
let largeCircle = UIView()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.addSubview(tabButton)
    self.addSubview(smallCircle)
    self.addSubview(largeCircle)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let height = self.frame.height
    tabButton.frame = CGRect(x: (self.frame.width-height)/2, y: 0, width: height, height: height)
    tabButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

    smallCircle.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width/2 - 2.5, y: height-10-8, width: 5, height: 5)
    smallCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    largeCircle.frame = CGRect(x:  self.frame.width/2 - 5, y: height-8, width: 10, height: 10)
    largeCircle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    print(smallCircle)
    print(largeCircle)
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    tabButton.layer.cornerRadius = tabButton.frame.width/2
}
```

}

Comment: What did you do? ```import UIKit```?

Comment: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) is not returning proper value for X , so instead i have added self.frame.width/2 and the value is proper now. Did you try using it?

Comment: yeah, i found it too. Do you know why  CGRectGetMidX not work well?

Comment: when you pass the CGRect to CGRectGetMidX , and if the value of x is 0 it works as per the method implies that is the reason you see it proper for the first UIView but if you supply a CGRect to CGRectGetMidX whose x value is not zero , it returns the value for mid point as X+Width/2 and not Width/2

Comment: If you use it like this it will still work with the CGRectGetMidX method CGRectGetMidX(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height))

Comment: you are right, but the third one should't appear if so.

Comment: And as per the documentation also it says "Returns the x- coordinate that establishes the center of a rectangle." so it returns the x-cordinate of the center with respect to the entire view and not the x-cordinate of the center of the individual view

Comment: the small circle and the large circle you are seeing on the third view is not of the third view it is of the second view which is shifted, try removing the subclass of the third view and it should still be seen since it belongs to second view and not the third one